# Apache redirect is failing for Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have `mod_rewrite` enabled on Apache2 and `AllowOverride All` in the default file. However Apache (After restarting) still can't seem to redirect when given a [pretty url](http://four.laravel.com/#pretty-urls) from Laravel.

*WORKS (Returns: Users!)*: `localhost/laratest/public/index.php/users`

*DOESN'T WORK (404)*: `localhost/laratest/public/users`

**My .htaccess: (I've also tried the one suggested in the [Documentation](http://four.laravel.com/#pretty-urls) to no avail)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Laravel routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

I am using the default LAMP stack and configuration in Ubuntu. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 .htaccess Not Rewriting URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912134/laravel-4-htaccess-not-rewriting-urls)

Comment: Solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912134/laravel-4-htaccess-not-rewriting-urls

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your `RewriteBase` to `/laratest/public`?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laratest/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the laravel website (http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls) try this other one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this also to no avail, I'll add it to the question.