# Laravel 4 routing not working due to .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, vhosts

I'm writing my steps and findings here so you can see what I've tried and what results I got. Any advice would be welcomed. I followed the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515278/956975).

I'm running [Laravel 4](http://four.laravel.com/), using [XAMMP version 1.8.2 with PHP 5.4.19 and Apache 2.4.4](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) on a Windows 7 machine and I'm simply still trying to get a local instance up and running.

In my case: `http://localhost/sos/sos_public/` is my main screen and that works, but when I try to get to `http://localhost/sos/sos_public/signup` I get this error: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` which has been talked about a lot on the net, and then I found [GaryJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515278/956975) stating that it might be an `.htaccess` issue, so I did what he suggested.

My `/app/routes.php` file looks like this (I've tried this with a `/` in front of `signup` too):

```
Route::get('signup', function()
{
    return 'hello!';
});     

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

**First:**

> Just for a laugh, see if `/index.php/hello` works. If so, then it's a `.htaccess` problem.

`http://localhost/sos/sos_public/index.php/signup` worked perfectly fine. So it's an `.htaccess` problem.

My `.htaccess` file looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**And:**

> if you're running `Apache 2.4`, note the changes since previous
>   versions, regarding `Require all granted` and `AllowOverride all` within a
>   `<Directory />...</Directory>` block on your virtual host.

I added this in my `httpd.conf file` as suggested by [Dalton Gore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16919509/956975) - got the `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException` error (changed this directory path to `/SOS/sos_public` and `C:/xammp/htdocs/SOS/sos_public/` and `C:/xammp/htdocs/SOS/sos_public` - same results):

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /SOS/sos_public>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Next:**

> Check if anything in `.htaccess` is working

I added `dsjkdsfghk` to my `.htaccess` file and immediately got an error, so I know my `.htaccess` file is being used.

**Then:**

> Try removing the `IfModule` conditional. As you've got access to the
>   host / vhost, you can soon enable that module if it's not - so it
>   doesn't need be checked on every request. Equally, try moving it out
>   of `.htaccess`, and into a `<Directory />...</Directory>` block in your
>   vhost - if you've got nothing else in your .htaccess it can then be
>   deleted as well.

- Having an empty `.htaccess` file caused a `404` error in my browser for `http://localhost/sos/sos_public/signup` (`http://localhost/sos/sos_public/` still worked).
- Removing the `.htaccess` file from `C:\xampp\htdocs\SOS\sos_public\` had the same results.

**Then:**

> Try: `<VirtualHost *:80> DocumentRoot
>   "/Users/amiterandole/Sites/laravelbackbone/public" ServerName
>   laravelbackbone.dev <Directory /> AllowOverride all Require all
>   granted </Directory> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> Options -MultiViews
>   RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^
>   index.php [L] </IfModule> </VirtualHost>`

I did that and just like Amit,

> I emptied out my `htaccess` file and tried the above and now nothing
>   seems to work.

Except where his `laravelbackbone.dev` pointed to his `Sites` folder root, I just got an `Error 400 - Bad request` on both `http://localhost/sos/sos_public/` and `http://localhost/sos/sos_public/signup` when I ran them in my browser.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` file looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xammp/htdocs/SOS/sos_public" 
    ServerName sos.dev
    <Directory /> 
        AllowOverride all 
        Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
        Options -MultiViews 
        RewriteEngine On 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
    </IfModule> 
</VirtualHost>
```

and in my .hosts file I obviously had:

```
127.0.0.1       sos.dev
```

**Lastly:**

> You've definitely got the `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file be
>   included (uncommented) within the main `httpd.conf`?

I have this uncommented - yes.

Another link I tried but to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17778222/956975 and http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working

What should I change where? 
What am I missing?

Comment: what does your routes.php file look like? do you have a `get route` to `signup`? something like `Route::get('signup', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});`

Comment: Yes, please look at my question and you'll see that I've got Route::get('signup', function()
{
    return 'hello!';
});

Comment: that's weird.. hmm. do you have an updated version of l4 perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Your ServerName is

```
sos.dev
```

And apache take this in consideration, you you must access your routes using:

```
http://sos.dev/
```

And NOT

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: I have the same issue: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException error wether I use http://sos.dev/ or http://localhost/ or a Error 400 Bad request when adding the VirtualHost as suggested.

Comment: Could you show us your REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING and REDIRECT_URL from the error page (Server/Request Data)?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the error of not enabling rewrite Engine in apache2

In linux,

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

In windows,

You should find httpd.conf file if it's not available in your apache look for apache2.conf file is another name for httpd.conf and enable the rewrite module for more info or here see how to do above-said procedure in this link
[Lost httpd.conf file located apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/lost-httpd-conf-file-located-apache)